# Unauthorised error when sending WebPush notification after upgrading Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, google-api, web-push

I'm using the [web-push](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push) to send push notification to web users using Chrome.
Everything worked fine after I followed the docs here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/

Today, after upgrading my Mac Chrome to version 74 I stopped receiving them.
Other clients (i.e. other Chromes) are still getting them.
When checking the server logs I see this error:

```
Error 401 (Unauthorized)!!1 //not a typo
That's all we know
```

(But in a fancy HTML format)

After running this line

```
webpush.sendNotification(webSubscription, '{payload: ...,userAuth: ...,userPublicKey: ...}')
```

I'm allowing myself to think that this cannot be my application error, because:

1. I followed and implemented exactly the code as they advise to
2. The code
   works for other clients perfectly (Mobile and Desktop)

**Only (as far as I know) do I get this error when trying to send a web push to browsers that created a subscription using Chrome v74.**

I'm emphasizing that there were no code changes whatsoever, the only change is the chrome version.

Comment: Ive down graded to v71, and stuff work again. Could it be an issue with v74?

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting the authentication error. 401 not authorized. My challenge is that I am in development so I did not consider any changes in the browser and have thought it was my encryption. What library are you using for the header-auth encryption with your private key. Obviously if you are not doing that then the newer browsers will reject. But I cannot at this juncture answer my own search.

Comment: I'm using web-push library to handle the encryption